# Scrapy ResponseNeverReceived error in loadPEM method

Tags: python, scrapy, ssl-certificate, ipython, twisted

```
from OpenSSL import SSL

from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory
from twisted.internet.ssl import PrivateCertificate
#from twisted.internet.ssl import DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory
from twisted.internet import ssl

class BrowserLikeContextFactory(ScrapyClientContextFactory):

            def creatorForNetloc(self, hostname, port):

            # trustRoot set to platformTrust() will use the platform's root CAs.
            #
            # This means that a website like https://www.cacert.org will be rejected
            # by default, since CAcert.org CA certificate is seldom shipped.

            with open ('path\\sample.pem') as f:

                keyAndCert = f.read()
                myClientCert = PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(keyAndCert)

              return optionsForClientTLS(hostname.decode("ascii"),

                trustRoot=platformTrust(),
                clientCertificate=myClientCert,
                extraCertificateOptions={
                'method': self._ssl_method,
              })
```

From the code above, I am trying to load a single PEM file of an organization (which I am authorized to use) to access their site. The file exists in the specified path with matching file name.

[image]

However, an error was encountered. Is this a problem with the file or how i implemented the code?

[image]

I created the .pem file from a .pfx file using this code

```
openssl pkcs12 -in sample.pfx -out sample.pem
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem loading the certificate from the pem-format data.  Instead it looks like a TLS handshake error when the connection is being set up.  Unfortunately OpenSSL errors are famously difficult to learn to interpret and usually don't have all the information you need to identify the problem.  This one just says the handshake was intentionally abandoned due to some error.  This might indicate a certificate validation error or a problem negotiation shared ciphers or something.  Unfortunately the problem also depends on the details of your certificate and the server.

Comment: okay thanks. what general steps should I take to identify the problem?

Comment: i have an authorized copy of the certificate with private keys so i assume the details are correct